# asio periodic timer

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I want to implement a java-like Timer by asio's timer, it used to execute code periodically.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

void print()
{
  std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
}

class WorldTimer
{
public:
    boost::posix_time::ptime now()
    {
        return _timer.expires_at();
    }
    void update()
    {
        _f();
        _timer.expires_at(_timer.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
        _timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&WorldTimer::update, this));
    }
    WorldTimer(boost::asio::io_service& io, void (*f)()) : _f(f), _timer(io){}
private:
    void (*_f)();
    boost::asio::deadline_timer _timer;
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    WorldTimer timer(io, print);
    timer.update();
    io.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Program only output Hello, world! once and pending there. asio doc has a [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer3.html), it works but I can not figure out what's the difference.

Yeah... timer has not been init a expire time, this is revised version:

```
class WorldTimer
{
public:
    boost::posix_time::ptime now()
    {
        return _timer.expires_at();
    }
    WorldTimer(boost::asio::io_service& io, void (*f)()) : _f(f), _timer(io, boost::posix_time::microseconds(0))
    {
        _timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&WorldTimer::update, this));
    }
private:
    void (*_f)();
    boost::asio::deadline_timer _timer;
    void update()
    {
        _f();
        _timer.expires_at(_timer.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
        _timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&WorldTimer::update, this));
    }
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    WorldTimer timer(io, print);
    io.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your deadline timer constructor is different from the one in the example. You need to [explicitly set the expiry time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/basic_deadline_timer/overload1.html).
The example code uses the other constructor which sets a [particular expiry time relative to now](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/basic_deadline_timer/overload3.html).

So the print-out you are seeing is related to your call to `update`, which calls

```
_timer.expires_at(_timer.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
```

and `_timer.expires_at()` has not been set yet...

Comment: BTW, I want to ask what will happen when timer expire but last time handler is still running?